# Do not open folds when moved over in insert mode

Tags: vim

I would like to keep folds as they are in insert mode. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_28.html reads:

> When in Insert mode, the fold at the cursor line is never closed.  That allows
>   you to see what you type!

This is very annoying and I don't want this. I close folds for good reasons, and want them to be closed until I `za` to toggle them.

In short, I would like folds to be opened/closed by `za` and absolutely nothing else.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_folds_closed_while_inserting_text doesn't work.

The closest I could get is this:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * setlocal foldclose=all
autocmd InsertLeave,WinLeave * setlocal foldclose&
```

which doesn't prevent folds from opening in insert mode but closes the opened fold once it's left. In the process, it closes all folds when entering insert mode.

As a bonus, it would be nice to open the fold if a character is actually is inserted in insert mode.

**Note:** I know "you aren't supposed to move around in insert mode". I just want the above behavior if it's possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that simply jumping over folds in insert mode is a good enough solution. the following works for me:

```
function! JumpOverFold(up)
    if a:up
        let foldn = foldclosed('.')
        if foldn == 1           "Fold begins at first line, can't jump over, go back
            exec 'normal gj'
        elseif foldn > 0
            exec 'normal gk'
        end
    else
        let foldn = foldclosedend('.')
        if foldn == line('$')   "Fold ends at last line, can't jump over, go back
            exec 'normal gk'
        elseif foldn > 0
            exec 'normal gj'
        end
    end
endfunction

inoremap <UP> <ESC>gk:call JumpOverFold(1)<CR>i
inoremap <DOWN> <ESC>gj:call JumpOverFold(0)<CR>i
```

Answer (score 2):

Insert mode is not for moving the cursor, it's for entering / replacing text! (Some deletion with `<BS>` or `<C-W>` is okay, but you should prefer the more powerful `d...` normal mode commands here.)

If you stick to this golden rule of vi / Vim editing (**only stay in insert mode for short editing bursts, use normal mode for everything else**), you won't be annoyed by this seemingly bad behavior!

Comment: Yes, I suspected this would be the instant answer. Thanks anyway, but I still want to achieve the above behavior.